# Is there a formal approach to rounding of numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers, rational-numbers

Math formalizes arithmetic as algebraic structures and operations on those structures. Rounding numbers is a common operation. Is there a commonly-accepted formalization of that operation as well?

E.g., could the rounding of rational numbers to integers be approached as an operation from a group to a sub-group (under addition, in this case)? What property would that function have? Would the same properties hold when rounding from real numbers to integers?

Comment: Well, people tend to approach such things from a computational point of view...it's not clear (to me) what algebraic properties you'd want such a thing to have.  Usually, people worry more about bias...if, say, you always round half integers down, then you might bias a sample downward.   But other viewpoints are possible, of course.

Comment: The property that we would like is f(a+b)= f(a)+f(b), bad luck, it doesn't work with rounding. We may have examples where f(a+b)<f(a)+f(b) or f(a+b)>f(a)+f(b). You consider 2 different cases with rational numbers, and real numbers. But due to continuity properties, these 2 domains are very similar for rounding considerations.

Comment: Interesting question! One answer that crosses my mind to begin formalizing may be to use metric spaces. That is, consider some distance function $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ over a set $X$, and some "nice" subset $R\subset X$ with a "rounding function" $\text{round}(\cdot):X\to R$ such that for any $r_1,r_2\in R$, $d(x,r_1)<d(x,r_2)\implies \text{round}(x)\neq r_2$ for all $x\in X$; and $\text{round}(r)=r$ for all $r\in R$. What exactly counts as a "nice" subset of $X$ would probably be something akin to a lattice.